# Find Which Statements Were Most Recently Compiled

Tags: sql-server-2008

On one of our SQL 2008 R2 servers, I have been experiencing an unusually high percentage of compiles related to the number of batching running. Usually the server runs a little high on this anyway (~25% of the total batches) but today its been more like 80%. Looking at the DMVs shows me what has been compiled but doesn't tell me when it happened.

I know that I can pull this data with profiler (and am doing so now) but was hoping to find somewhere that this was stored in history.

Has anyone found a way to do this or is Profiler the only way?

Comment: Please don't trace with profiler. You're only going to make the load on your server worse. At the very least use a server-side trace (no UI) or extended events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `creation_time` in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
  ON s.plan_handle = p.plan_handle
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle)
  ORDER BY creation_time DESC;
```